# lftp: How to list transfer size before (mirror) operation?

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, lftp

I have an lftp job that is going to transfer a large amount of data (30GB) to a slow remote FTP server. For various reasons, it won't work in one shot (which probably will take days anyway) but has been working fine in increments.

So, I'd like to get the size of the mirror operation before it commences to understand how much data remains, but I haven't figured out a way of doing that yet. It would be fine for this to be a separate command.

I tried a debug log and a dry run, neither of which produce a size output.

What can I look at to figure this out?

Comment: How have you been transferring so far? What is the full command? And what output or response do you get from the server or command while it is running or when it begins or completes each portion?